# Spark: subtract two DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

In Spark version *1.2.0* one could use `subtract` with 2 `SchemRDD`s to end up with only the different content from the first one

```
val onlyNewData = todaySchemaRDD.subtract(yesterdaySchemaRDD)
```

`onlyNewData` contains the rows in `todaySchemRDD` that do not exist in `yesterdaySchemaRDD`.

How can this be achieved with `DataFrames` in Spark version *1.3.0*?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

According to the [**Scala** API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), doing:

```
dataFrame1.except(dataFrame2)
```

will return a new DataFrame containing rows in dataFrame1 but not in dataframe2.

Comment: What if I need to perform the exception not on the whole row, but only a column? E.g. `dataFrame1` rows except those where the `primary_key` does not appear in `dataFrame2`? (looks like `subtractByKey` for RDDs, but preferably for a dataframe.

Comment: @KatyaHandler You can use a `LEFT JOIN` coupled with a `IS NULL` on the joined dataframe's key. The sql for this is something like: `SELECT * FROM df1 LEFT JOIN df2 ON df1.id = df2.id WHERE df2.id IS NULL`

Comment: @KatyaHandler: I'm also looking for the same solution.. could you please tell me how did you acheive this using DF, can you please update the answer.

Comment: @KatyaHandler you can do that with a `LEFT ANTI` join. `dataFrame1.join(dataFrame2, "key_col", "left_anti")`

Comment: except() method is working fine when ran on small set of input data locally . But when I ran over S3 bucket data, except is not working properly . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188415/spark-dataframe-except-method-issue

Comment: Is there an implementation in Pyspark?

Comment: @Jan33 [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67700696/7465462) you can see my answer in Pyspark

Answer (score 76):

In **PySpark** it would be [`subtract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.subtract)

```
df1.subtract(df2)
```

or [`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.exceptAll) if duplicates need to be preserved

```
df1.exceptAll(df2)
```

Comment: this is the correct answer as of some releases ago. definitely for 2.1.0.

Comment: Hey @Teja The subtract method seems to be case sensitive. Is it possible to ignore case while subtracting

Comment: Note that `subtract()` is available for Python Spark's dataframe, but the function does not exist for Scala Spark's dataframe.

Comment: As I understand it, subtract() is the same as "left anti" join where the join condition is every column and both dataframes have the same columns.

Answer (score 17):

From Spark 1.3.0, you can use [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) with `'left_anti'` option:

```
df1.join(df2, on='key_column', how='left_anti')
```

These are **Pyspark APIs**, but I guess there is a correspondent function in Scala too.

Comment: This is very useful in some situation. Suppose. I have two dataframes with id, category
dataframe1 id,category

Comment: I have added a new answer for explaining this.

Answer (score 14):

I tried subtract, but the result was not consistent.
If I run `df1.subtract(df2)`, not all lines of df1 are shown on the result dataframe, probably due `distinct` cited on the docs.

[`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.exceptAll) solved my problem:
`df1.exceptAll(df2)`

Comment: New in Spark version 2.4. True, but I don't think it works for prior versions! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: You can duplicate that in versions 2+ doing `DataFrame(df1._jdf.exceptAll(df2._jdf), sqlContext)`

Comment: This is just a principle of SQL: set operations like subtract, intersect, etc. are just that: set operations. Hence, they will convert tables to a set first (which has no duplicate entries)

Comment: @BdEngineer , could not find except function on docs, is it PySpark or Spark Scala? ( https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract )

Comment: @ArthurJulião For pyspark use `subtract`.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract

Answer (score 4):

For me, `df1.subtract(df2)` was inconsistent. Worked correctly on one dataframe, but not on the other. That was because of duplicates. `df1.exceptAll(df2)` returns a new dataframe with the records from df1 that do not exist in df2, including any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

From Spark 2.4.0 - [`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.exceptAll)

```
data_cl = reg_data.exceptAll(data_fr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ric S's answer is the best solution in some situation like below.

From Spark 1.3.0, you can use join with 'left_anti' option:

```
df1.join(df2, on='key_column', how='left_anti')
```

These are Pyspark APIs, but I guess there is a correspondent function in Scala too.

This is very useful in some situation. Suppose. I have two dataframes

```
dataframe1
-----------------------------------------
|id | category                           |
-----------------------------------------
|1  | [{"type":"sport","name","soccer"}] |
-----------------------------------------
    
dataframe2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id | category                                                               |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  | [{"type":"sport","name","soccer"}, {"type":"player","name":"ronaldo"}] |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here it is not possible to use exceptAll() or substract()