# Spark Scala filter DataFrame where value not in another DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two DataFrames: `a` and `b`. This is how they look like:

```
a
-------
v1 string
v2 string

roughly hundreds of millions rows


b
-------
v2 string

roughly tens of millions rows
```

I would like to keep rows from DataFrame `a` where `v2` is not in `b("v2")`.

I know I could use left join and filter where right side is null or SparkSQL with "not in" construction. I bet there is better approach though.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but join+filter should work quite well too! I think most of the work from join+filter is unavoidable in any solution.

Comment: Yeah, actually SparkSQL worked very fast. Also - it's not duplicate - I needed negative filter.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using the `except` method of [Dataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset), wich "*Returns a new Dataset containing rows in this Dataset but not in another Dataset*"

Answer (score 1):

Use `PairRDDFunctions.subtractByKey`:

> def **subtractByKey**[W](other: RDD[(K, W)])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[W]): RDD[(K, V)]
>
> Return an RDD with the pairs from this whose keys are not in other.

(There are variants that offer control over the partitioning. See the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).)

So you would do `a.rdd.map { case (v1, v2) => (v2, v1) }.subtractByKey(b.rdd).toDF`.

Comment: Perhaps a pure DataFrame-based solution exists as well? I don't use DataFrames much, sorry. But it shouldn't be too painful to jump back to RDDs, use `subtractByKey` and go back to DataFrames.

Comment: You could use [except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@except(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])

Comment: Ah, `except` is the perfect answer! Want to post it as a separate answer?

Comment: sure, I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider your dataframe `a` looks like below.

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|  v1|
|  v2|
+----+
```

Consider your dataframe `b` looks like below.

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|  v2|
+----+
```

**APPROACH 1:** 
**-------------------**

You can use dataframe's `join` method and use the type of join as `left_anti` to find out the values that are in dataframe `a` but not in dataframe `b`. The code is given below :

```
a.as('a).join(b.as('b),$"a.col1" === $"b.col1","left_anti").show()
```

Please find the result below :

[image]

**APPROACH 2:** 
**-------------------**

You can use `sql` which is similar to Sql server/Oracle etc to do this. For this, first you have to register your dataframe as temp table (which will reside in spark's memory) and then write the sql on top of that table.

```
a.registerTempTable("table_a")
b.registerTempTable("table_b")
spark.sql("select * from table_a a where not exists(select 1 from table_b b where a.col1=b.col1)").show()
```

Please find the result below :

[image]