# subtractByKey for Spark Dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have two DataFrames:

```
headers = ["id", "info"]

a = sc.parallelize([(1, "info1"), (2, "info2"), (3, "info3")]).toDF(headers)
b = sc.parallelize([(2, "info2new")]).toDF(headers)
```

And I want to obtain the files from `a` but overwrite those rows in `a` that appear in `b`. So the desired output is

```
+---+--------+
| id|    info|
+---+--------+
|  1|   info1|
|  2|info2new|
|  3|   info3|
+---+--------+
```

Now, I could convert my DataFrames to RDDs, and use `subtractByKey`, but this forces me to convert to RDDs, map to (key, value) tuples and then convert back to DataFrames. Meh.

I looked around and [saw the functions `except` and `subtract` for Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes) DataFrames, but these require the rows to be exact duplicates, which mine are not.

The way I am considering doing this now is like so:

```
a1 = a.select(*(col(x).alias(x + '_old') for x in a.columns))
b1 = b.select(*(col(x).alias(x + '_new') for x in b.columns))
x = a1.join(b1, a1['id_old'] == b1['id_new"], "outer")
```

Then I would register x as a tempTable and write a SQL query that would return the old data unless the new data is not null. But I don't think this is particularly clean either!

Any good ideas?

Comment: Or just perform left outer join with `coalesce` / `case when`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the best way but you could do `left outer` `join` with a `UDF` and some cleaning stuff.

**Scala:**

```
// UDF to choose info value
val newInfo = udf[String,String,String]((infoA,infoB) => {
  if (infoB == null)
    infoA
  else
    infoB
})

// join -> add col("newInfo") -> drop info cols -> rename "newInfo"
a.join(b, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
  .withColumn("newInfo", newInfo(a("info"), b("info")))
  .drop(a("info"))
  .drop(b("info"))
  .withColumnRenamed("newInfo", "info")
  .show()
```