# How to subtract DataFrames using subset of columns in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I perform filter operation on Dataframe1 using Dataframe2. 
I want to remove rows from DataFrame1 for below matching condition

```
Dataframe1.col1 = Dataframe2.col1
Dataframe1.col2 = Dataframe2.col2
```

My question is different than substract two dataframes because while substract we use all columns but in my question I want to use limited number of columns

Comment: My question is different than substract two dataframes because while substract we use all columns but in my question I want to use limited number of columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**join** with "**left_anti**"

```
scala> df1.show
+----+-----+-----+
|col1| col2| col3|
+----+-----+-----+
|   1|  one|   ek|
|   2|  two|  dho|
|   3|three|theen|
|   4| four|chaar|
+----+-----+-----+


scala> df2.show
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2| col3|
+----+----+-----+
|   2| two|  dho|
|   4|four|chaar|
+----+----+-----+


scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("col1", "col2"), "left_anti").show
+----+-----+-----+
|col1| col2| col3|
+----+-----+-----+
|   1|  one|   ek|
|   3|three|theen|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me! Here is using Java  Dataset<Row>   filterDf =  dataset1.join(dataset2,JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"col1", "col2"}).iterator()).asScala().toSeq(),"left_anti");

Comment: @Gaurang If possible, please edit the question subject from "How to filter data frames in spark" to more specific. It helps others with their specific need.

Comment: do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: DataFrames subtract over a subset of columns? just like you have described in your description.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion..I change question title.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of :[Spark: subtract two DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes) if both datasets have exact same coulmns

If you want custom join condition then you can use "anti" join. Here is the pysaprk version

Creating two data frames:

Dataframe1 :

```
l1 = [('col1_row1', 10), ('col1_row2', 20), ('col1_row3', 30)
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(l1).toDF('col1','col2')

df1.show()
+---------+----+
|     col1|col2|
+---------+----+
|col1_row1|  10|
|col1_row2|  20|
|col1_row3|  30|
+---------+----+
```

Dataframe2 :

```
l2 = [('col1_row1', 10), ('col1_row2', 20), ('col1_row4', 40)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(l2).toDF('col1','col2')
df2.show()
+---------+----+
|     col1|col2|
+---------+----+
|col1_row1|  10|
|col1_row2|  20|
|col1_row4|  40|
+---------+----+
```

**Using subtract api :**

```
df_final = df1.subtract(df2)
df_final.show()
+---------+----+
|     col1|col2|
+---------+----+
|col1_row3|  30|
+---------+----+
```

**Using left_anti :**

Join condition:

```
join_condition = [df1["col1"] == df2["col1"], df1["col2"] == df2["col2"]]
```

Join finally

```
df_final = df1.join(df2, join_condition, 'left_anti')
df_final.show()
+---------+----+
|     col1|col2|
+---------+----+
|col1_row3|  30|
+---------+----+
```