# Keeping identifier in exceptAll in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was curious if there is an easy way to keep an identifying ID in the exceptALL command in PySpark. For example, suppose I have two dataframes (DF1,DF2) both with an ID column and another column "A." I want to keep the rows in DF1 that have a value for "A" not in DF2, so essentially I am trying to keep the identifier with the usual output of exceptAll. I attached an image with the ideal output.

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [leftanti join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186888/left-anti-join-in-spark) in Spark:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, "Dog"],
  [2, "Cat"],
  [3, "Dog"]
], ["id", "A"])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
  [4, "Dog"],
  [5, "Elmo"]
], ["id", "A"])

df1.join(df2, ["A"], "leftanti").show()

# +---+---+
# |  A| id|
# +---+---+
# |Cat|  2|
# +---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

pyspark's dataframe method `subtract` should give you what you want. See [Spark: subtract two DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes) for more details.

Using `exceptAll` will not give the results you wanted, as it will retain the second `dog` entry in `df1` because `exceptAll` keeps duplicates.

Given your dataframes :

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([{'id': 1, 'A': 'dog'},
                             {'id': 2, 'A': 'cat'},
                             {'id': 3, 'A': 'dog'}])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([{'id': 4, 'A': 'dog'},
                             {'id': 5, 'A': 'elmo'}])
```

Use `subtract` on column of interest (i.e. `A`), then join the results back to original dataframe to get the remaining columns (i.e. `id`).

```
except_df = df1.select('A').subtract(df2.select('A'))

except_df.join(df1, on='A').show()

+---+---+
|  A| id|
+---+---+
|cat|  2|
+---+---+
```