# Spark: subtract dataframes but preserve duplicate values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have two Spark SQL dataframes `A` and `B`. I want to subtract the items in `B` from the items in `A` while preserving duplicates from `A`.

I followed the instructions to use `DataFrame.except()` that I found in another StackOverflow question (["Spark: subtract two DataFrames"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes)), but that function removes all duplicates from the original dataframe `A`.

As a conceptual example, if I have two dataframes:

```
words     = [the, quick, fox, a, brown, fox]
stopWords = [the, a]
```

then I want the output to be, in any order:

```
words - stopWords = [quick, brown, fox, fox]
```

I observed that the RDD function `subtract()` preserves the duplicates, but the Spark-SQL function `except()` removes duplicates in the resulting data frame. I don't understand why the `except()` output produces only unique values.

Here is a complete demonstration:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
// EXAMPLE USING RDDs
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
var wordsRdd = sc.parallelize(List("the", "quick", "fox", "a", "brown", "fox"))
var stopWordsRdd = sc.parallelize(List("a", "the"))

var wordsWithoutStopWordsRdd = wordsRdd.subtract(stopWordsRdd)
wordsWithoutStopWordsRdd.take(10)
// res11: Array[String] = Array(quick, brown, fox, fox)

// ---------------------------------------------------------------
// EXAMPLE USING DATAFRAMES
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
var wordsDf = wordsRdd.toDF()
var stopWordsDf = stopWords.toDF()
var wordsWithoutStopWordsDf = wordsDf.except(stopWordsDf)

wordsWithoutStopWordsDf.show(10)
// +-----+
// |value|
// +-----+
// |  fox|
// |brown|
// |quick|
// +-----+
```

I want to preserve duplicates because I am generating frequency tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I bet it is because it uses a `Set` instead of a `List`. Besides what you are looking for is a `join`.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: A `join` performs an intersection, right? The result will be values that are in both `A` and `B`. I want the difference between them, not the intersection.

Comment: Depends on join's type. By the way check my answer

Comment: Doesn't `DataFrame.subtract()` do exactly what you asked? Or was it not available in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val words = sc.parallelize(List("the", "quick", "fox", "a", "brown", "fox")).toDF("id")
val stopwords = sc.parallelize(List("a", "the")).toDF("id")


words.join(stopwords, words("id") === stopwords("id"), "left_outer")
     .where(stopwords("id").isNull)
     .select(words("id")).show()
```

The output is:

```
+-----+
|   id|
+-----+
|  fox|
|  fox|
|brown|
|quick|
+-----+
```

Comment: That left outer join approach is really slick. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a different idea in case we have mutli columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `exceptAll`:

https://hyukjin-spark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll.html

For example:

```
val words = sc.parallelize(List("the", "quick", "fox", "a", "brown", "fox")).toDF("id")
val stopwords = sc.parallelize(List("a", "the")).toDF("id")

words.exceptAll(stopwords).show()
```

Output should be:

```
+-----+
|   id|
+-----+
|quick|
|  fox|
|  fox|
|brown|
+-----+
```