# Spark 2.3: subtract dataframes but preserve duplicate values (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Copying example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565978/spark-subtract-dataframes-but-preserve-duplicate-values) question:
As a conceptual example, if I have two dataframes:

```
words     = [the, quick, fox, a, brown, fox]
stopWords = [the, a]
```

then I want the output to be, in any order:

```
words - stopWords = [quick, brown, fox, fox]
```

`ExceptAll` can do this in 2.4 but I cannot upgrade. The answer in the linked question is specific to a dataframe:

```
words.join(stopwords, words("id") === stopwords("id"), "left_outer")
     .where(stopwords("id").isNull)
     .select(words("id")).show()
```

as in you need to know the pkey and the other columns.

Can anyone come up with an answer that will work on any dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's easier to do `df1.except(df2)` and then join the results with `df1` to get all the duplicates.

Full code:

```
def exceptAllCustom(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val except = df1.except(df2)

    val columns = df1.columns
    val colExpr: Column = df1(columns.head) <=> except(columns.head)
    val joinExpression = columns.tail.foldLeft(colExpr) { (colExpr, p) =>
        colExpr && df1(p) <=> except(p)
    }

    val join = df1.join(except, joinExpression, "inner")

    join.select(df1("*"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation for you all. I have tested in Spark 2.4.2, it should work for 2.3 too (not 100% sure)

```
    val df1 = spark.createDataset(Seq("the","quick","fox","a","brown","fox")).toDF("c1")
    val df2 = spark.createDataset(Seq("the","a")).toDF("c1")

    exceptAllCustom(df1, df2, Seq("c1")).show()


  def exceptAllCustom(df1 : DataFrame, df2 : DataFrame, pks : Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
    val notNullCondition = pks.foldLeft(lit(0==0))((column,cName) => column && df2(cName).isNull)
    val joinCondition = pks.foldLeft(lit(0==0))((column,cName) => column && df2(cName)=== df1(cName))
    val result = df1.join(df2, joinCondition, "left_outer")
       .where(notNullCondition)

    pks.foldLeft(result)((df,cName) => df.drop(df2(cName)))
  }
```

Result -

```
+-----+
|   c1|
+-----+
|quick|
|  fox|
|brown|
|  fox|
+-----+
```

Comment: Is there a solution for when pkeys are not known? This method should be able to be applied on any 2 dfs, like the ExceptAll in 2.4

Comment: that is possible, read all columns from dataframe's schema and use it.

Comment: This is not working for me. Try `df1 = [1,2,2,3,4,5]` and `df2 = [1,3,4,5]`. Result should be `[2,2]` but this solution returns `[ ]`.

Comment: Ok, it works in 2.4 but in 2.3 you get the error: `Resolved attribute(s) c1#8 missing from c1#3 in operator !Filter` Due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14948

Comment: It does not work if there is more than 1 column. 

df1:
```+---+------+
|id |name  |
+---+------+
|1  |Beth  |
|2  |Alan  |
|3  |Rachel|
|1  |Beth  |
|2  |Alan  |
+---+------+```

df2:
```+---+------+
|id |name  |
+---+------+
|3  |Rachel|
+---+------+```

Expected:
```+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|2  |Alan|
|2  |Alan|
|1  |Beth|
|1  |Beth|
+---+----+```

Actual:
```+---+----+----+
|id |name|id  |
+---+----+----+
|1  |Beth|null|
|2  |Alan|null|
|1  |Beth|null|
|2  |Alan|null|
+---+----+----+```

Comment: Yes that's the problem, there shouldn't be the extra column. Why is it not being removed when you do `pks.foldLeft(result)((df,cName) => df.drop(df2(cName)))`?

Comment: This also does not account for null values. e.g. `df1 = [(null, cat), (1, mouse)]` and `df2 = [(null, cat)]` should return `res = [(1,mouse)]` but it returns `(null,cat)` as well