# get duplicated rows based on column spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to drop duplicated rows based on the column id. How can i get the dropped data which have duplicate "id"? This is the code that I've been working on for now.

```
val datatoBeInserted = data.select("id", "is_enabled", "code", "description", "gamme", "import_local", "marque", "type_marketing", "reference", "struct", "type_tarif", "family_id", "range_id", "article_type_id")
val cleanedData = datatoBeInserted.dropDuplicates("id")
```

Using the above query, cleanedData will give all rows without duplicates of "id". Now, I want to figure out which rows have been filtered out because of duplicates.

Comment: did you try `dataToBeInserted.except(cleanedData)`?

Comment: @philantrovert please answer the question :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I've flagged it as a duplicate :)

Comment: duplicate of which one ? @philantrovert

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to find the data which is dropped

```
val datatoBeInserted = data.select("id", "is_enabled", "code", "description", "gamme", "import_local", "marque", "type_marketing", "reference", "struct", "type_tarif", "family_id", "range_id", "article_type_id")

val cleanedData = datatoBeInserted.dropDuplicates("id")

val droppedData = datatoBeInserted.except(cleanedData)
```

All the best :)

Comment: thanks , i have already tried it , but it takes too much time for huge data thanks , is there any other solution

Comment: @MaherHTB  The problem is that when looking if there's a column with the same id in cleanedData, it could be anywhere. So the operation has to do an enormous amount of data shuffling => slow