# Spark Dataframe except method Issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case to minus two dataframes . So i have used the dataframe except() method.

This is working fine locally on smaller set of data.

But when I ran over AWS S3 bucket ,the except() method is not making minus as expected . Is there anything needs to be taken care on distributed environment ?

Does anyone faced this similar issue ?

Here is my sample code

```
val values = List(List("One", "2017-07-01T23:59:59.000", "2017-11-04T23:59:58.000", "A", "Yes") 
  , List("Two", "2017-07-01T23:59:59.000", "2017-11-04T23:59:58.000", "X", "No") 
  , List("Three", "2017-07-09T23:59:59.000", "2017-12-05T23:59:58.000", "M", "Yes") 
  , List("Four", "2017-11-01T23:59:59.000", "2017-12-09T23:59:58.000", "A", "No") 
  , List("Five", "2017-07-09T23:59:59.000", "2017-12-05T23:59:58.000", "", "No") 
  ,List("One", "2017-07-01T23:59:59.000", "2017-11-04T23:59:58.000", "", "No")
)
  .map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4)))

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val df = values.toDF("KEY", "ROW_START_DATE", "ROW_END_DATE", "CODE", "Indicator")

val filterCond = (col("ROW_START_DATE") <= "2017-10-31T23:59:59.999" && col("ROW_END_DATE") >= "2017-10-31T23:59:59.999" && col("CODE").isin("M", "A", "R", "G"))


val Filtered = df.filter(filterCond)
val Excluded = df.except(df.filter(filterCond))
```

Expected Output:

```
df.show(false)
Filtered.show(false)
Excluded.show(false)
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|KEY  |ROW_START_DATE         |ROW_END_DATE           |CODE|Indicator|
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|One  |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|A   |Yes      |
|Two  |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|X   |No       |
|Three|2017-07-09T23:59:59.000|2017-12-05T23:59:58.000|M   |Yes      |
|Four |2017-11-01T23:59:59.000|2017-12-09T23:59:58.000|A   |No       |
|Five |2017-07-09T23:59:59.000|2017-12-05T23:59:58.000|    |No       |
|One  |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|    |No       |
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|KEY  |ROW_START_DATE         |ROW_END_DATE           |CODE|Indicator|
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|One  |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|A   |Yes      |
|Three|2017-07-09T23:59:59.000|2017-12-05T23:59:58.000|M   |Yes      |
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|KEY |ROW_START_DATE         |ROW_END_DATE           |CODE|Indicator|
+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|Four|2017-11-01T23:59:59.000|2017-12-09T23:59:58.000|A   |No       |
|Two |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|X   |No       |
|Five|2017-07-09T23:59:59.000|2017-12-05T23:59:58.000|    |No       |
|One |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|    |No       |
+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
```

But Getting something like below when ran over S3 bucket

```
Filtered.show(false)
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|KEY  |ROW_START_DATE         |ROW_END_DATE           |CODE|Indicator|
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|One  |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|A   |Yes      |
|Three|2017-07-09T23:59:59.000|2017-12-05T23:59:58.000|M   |Yes      |
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+

Excluded.show(false)

+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|KEY |ROW_START_DATE         |ROW_END_DATE           |CODE|Indicator|
+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
|One |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|A   |Yes      |---> wrong
|Four|2017-11-01T23:59:59.000|2017-12-09T23:59:58.000|A   |No       |
|Two |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|X   |No       |
|Five|2017-07-09T23:59:59.000|2017-12-05T23:59:58.000|    |No       |
|One |2017-07-01T23:59:59.000|2017-11-04T23:59:58.000|    |No       |
+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----+---------+
```

Is there any other way to perform minus of two spark dataframe ?

Comment: what is `Filtered.show(false)` in s3 bucket?

Comment: Filtered.show(false) is working same in both environments . Updated the S3 output

Comment: you are trying as `val Excluded = df.except(df.filter(filterCond))` why don't you try as `val Excluded = df.except(Filtered)`?

Comment: does it make a difference ?

Comment: try it :) I don't know what's there to loose for trying?

Comment: yup...let me try this :) ...thanks

Comment: I have tried this option..No Luck.

Comment: thats a wierd error. may be you should clean everything. make new jars and run it.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same behavior with `DataFrame.subtract`. Can you post your solution?

Comment: I have not found any solution to this and so I have changed my programming functionality. Not sure why this issue is popping up, may be because of spark's distributed nature of processing.

Comment: When you say you changed, did you do something different in Spark or switch away from Spark? Thanks for your speedy response.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same behaviour of different output with large dataset. Has anyone got it working. Except give different outputs. I have also tried using action on the dataframe before performing except operation but it does not helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use leftanti join on the two dataframes based on the uniqueness on the two dataframes and that would give you the output that you were expecting from the except operation.

```
val diffdf = df1.join(df2,Seq("uniquekey"),"leftanti")
```

Comment: @nikunj-kakadiyakunj I agree that this method of using "anti join" helps us achieve our requirement. But any idea why except method doesn't work? Ideally it should have given the same result.

Comment: @boom_clap Theoritically it should work but might have something odd in the data values or could be something because of the transformation applied without action but I haven't check that along with the test data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

S3 isn't quite a filesystem, and [it can surface in spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html)

1. Try to verify that the data written to s3 is the same as what you get when using a file:// dest. As there's a risk that things get lost on the way.
2. Then try putting a Thread.sleep(10000) between writing to s3 and reading; that will show if directory inconsistency is surfacing.
3. If you are on EMR, try with their consistent EMR option
4. And try with the s3a:// connector

If it doesn't work with s3a:// file a SPARK- JIRA on issues.apache.org, put s3a in the text too, including this code snippet (which is implicitly licensing it to the ASF). I can then replicate it into a test & see if I can see it, and if so, whether it goes away when I turn s3guard on in Hadoop 3.1+