# comparing the data in two RDDS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

`rdd1`:

```
(m1,p1)
(m1,p2)
(m1,p3)
(m2,p1)
(m2,p2)
(m2,p3)
(m2,p4)
```

`rdd2`:

```
(m1,p1)
(m1,p2)
(m1,p3)
(m2,p1)
(m2,p2)
(m2,p3)
```

I have two rdds `rdd1` and `rdd2` I want to compare both rdds and to print the differences i.e `(m2,p4)` which is not present in `rdd2`.

I tried `rdd1.substractbykey(rdd2)`  and  `rdd1.substract(rdd2)` I am not getting any data please assist

Comment: You can use `df1.except(df2)`  More explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
rdd1:

(m1,p1) (m1,p2) (m1,p3) (m2,p1) (m2,p2) (m2,p3) (m2,p4)

rdd2:

(m1,p1) (m1,p2) (m1,p3) (m2,p1) (m2,p2) (m2,p3)
```

Comment: With your Syntex try to add void null value as an integer .

Answer (score 0):

You can using `full outer join` in dataframes:

```
def find_not_null(row):
     if(row['col1'] is None):
         return (row['col3'], row['col4'])
     else:
         return (row['col1'], row['col2'])

diff_rdd = rdd1.toDF(['col1', 'col2']). \
   join(rdd1.toDF(['col3', 'col4']), \ 
        col('col1') == col('col2') and col('col3') == col('col4'), \
        'full_outer'). \
   filter(lambda x: x['col1'] is None or x['col3'] is None).rdd. \
   map(find_not_null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need `RDD`s, than you could get your result using `subtract` and `union`.

Assuming that you're interested in differences from the both sides, this will work:

```
val left = sc.makeRDD(Seq(("m1","p1"), ("m1","p2"), ("m1","p3"), ("m2","p1"), ("m2","p2"), ("m2","p3"), ("m2","p4")))
val right = sc.makeRDD(Seq(("m1","p1"), ("m1","p2"), ("m1","p3"), ("m2","p1"), ("m2","p2"), ("m2","p3"), ("m3","p1")))

val output = left.subtract(right).union(right.subtract(left))
output.collect() // Array[(String, String)] = Array((m2,p4), (m3,p1))
```

On the other hand, if don't mind keeping "full outer join" in memory, you could achieve the same using `cogroup`:

```
val output = left.cogroup(right).flatMap { case (k, (i1, i2)) => 
  val s1 = i1.toSet
  val s2 = i2.toSet
  val diff = (s1 diff s2) ++ (s2 diff s1)
  diff.toList.map(k -> _)
}
output.collect() // Array[(String, String)] = Array((m2,p4), (m3,p1))
```