# Inconsistent results when trying to find records deleted between 2 files using Spark Dataset (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using the Spark Java API and I'm trying to find records that were **deleted** between 2 files using Dataset. For one test that I have, I'm comparing 2 identical files that have 2 columns. I use one of the columns as a type of PK (if the PK is not on the newer file is a delete).

Example of the file

> ID|TYPE
>   ABC|BUY
>   CDE|BUY
>   FGH|SELL

Datasets were created as:

```
Dataset<Row> previous/actual = sparkSession.read().
                       .option("inferSchema","true")
                       .option("header","true")
                       .option("delimiter","|")
                       .csv(*pathToFile*);
```

I have inconsistent results for the scenarios below

Example 1:

```
Dataset<Row> deleted = previous.join(actual,previous.col("ID").equalTo(actual.col("ID")),"leftanti");
```

As a result I get:

> |
>   The pipe is printed in my output file. If I invoke deleted.show() I get null|null

Example 2 is very similar but I calculate a hash from all columns (for both datasets separately ) as:

```
//columns has the content of previous.columns();
previous = previous.withColumn("hash", functions.hash(columns.toArray(new Column[0])));
```

I replace the ID with the hash in the query

```
Dataset<Row> deleted = previous.join(actual,previous.col("hash").equalTo(actual.col("hash")),"leftanti");
```

But now my result, as expected, is a blank file.
Why are the results different?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem,you want records from both Dataset which is not present in one of the dataset,then you can go for except method.

Same is the reference here [Spark: subtract two DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes)

dataFrame1.except(dataFrame2)
will return a new DataFrame containing rows in dataFrame1 but not in dataframe2.
or it does not result just do vice versa.

dataFrame2.except(dataFrame1)

Comment: Tarun, I want records from the previous Dataset that were deleted (not modified). The “ID” no longer exists. If the same ID is present in both files but with a different TYPE than it’s a record I don’t care bc it’s an update not a delete.

Comment: But more important. Why I had different results when running with my "PK" column and a "hash" column on the same datasets?