# How to display mismatched report with a label in spark 1.6 - scala except function?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6

Consider there are 2 dataframes df1 and df2.

df1 has below data

```
 A | B
-------
 1 | m
 2 | n
 3 | o
```

df2 has below data

```
 A | B
-------
 1 | m
 2 | n
 3 | p
```

`df1.except(df2)` returns

```
 A | B
-------
 3 | o
 3 | p
```

How to display the result as below?

```
df1:  3 | o
df2:  3 | p
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) df1.except(df2), Returns a new DataFrame containing rows in this frame but not in another frame. i.e, it will return rows that are in DF1 and not in DF2. Thus a custom except function could be written as:

```
def except(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val edf1 = df1.except(df2).withColumn("df", lit("df1"))
  val edf2 = df2.except(df1).withColumn("df", lit("df2"))
  edf1.union(edf2)
}
//Output
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B| df|
+---+---+---+
|  3|  o|df1|
|  3|  p|df2|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes

Comment: Can this field be added to beginning of df?

Comment: How does it matter? val edf = edf1.union(edf2)
val cols = edf.columns.filter(c => !c.equalsIgnoreCase("df"))
edf.select("df", cols: _*)