# Remove duplicates from Spark SQL joining two dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I Have two spark DFs which I need to join. Only select Values from df2 which are present in df1 there shouldn't be repeated rows.

For example:

df1:

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+
|a            |b              |val       |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 202003101750|   202003101700|1712384842|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|1590554927|
| 202003101730|   202003101700|1930860788|
| 202003101730|   202003101600|    101713|
| 202003101720|   202003101700|1261542412|
| 202003101720|   202003101600|   1824155|
| 202003101710|   202003101700| 912601761|
+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

df2:

```
+-------------+---------------+
|a            |b              |
+-------------+---------------+
| 202003101800|   202003101700|
| 202003101800|   202003101700|
| 202003101750|   202003101700|
| 202003101750|   202003101700|
| 202003101750|   202003101700|
| 202003101750|   202003101700|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|
+-------------+---------------+
```

I am doing the following:

`df1.join(df2, Seq("a", "b"), "leftouter").where(col("val").isNotNull)`
But my output has several repeated rows.

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+
|a            |b              |val       |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 202003101750|   202003101700|1712384842|
| 202003101750|   202003101700|1712384842|
| 202003101750|   202003101700|1712384842|
| 202003101750|   202003101700|1712384842|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|1590554927|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|1590554927|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|1590554927|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|1590554927||
+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

I am trying to achieve an except like operation if val is dropped from df1. But `except` doesn't seem to work. 
For example the following is the desired operation
`df1.drop(col("val")).except("df2")` 
The schema is as follows for df1:

```
root
 |-- a: String (nullable = true)
 |-- b: String (nullable = true)
 |-- val: long (nullable = true)
```

Also, What exactly is the difference between left-outer join and except? 
Expected output:

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+
|a            |b              |val       |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 202003101750|   202003101700|1712384842|
| 202003101740|   202003101700|1590554927||
+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: please add your expected output..?

Comment: @Shu added comment. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`LeftOuter`**](https://medium.com/@achilleus/https-medium-com-joins-in-apache-spark-part-1-dabbf3475690) join will get all the rows from left table and matching rows from right table.

[**`Except`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29557582) will give rows that are not exist in second dataframe compared to first dataframe(without duplicates).

For your case you can use `inner` (or) `outer` join with dropDuplicates.

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("a", "b"), "inner").dropDuplicates().show()
//+------------+------------+----------+
//|           a|           b|       val|
//+------------+------------+----------+
//|202003101740|202003101700|1590554927|
//|202003101750|202003101700|1712384842|
//+------------+------------+----------+

df1.join(df2, Seq("a", "b"), "rightouter").where(col("val").isNotNull).dropDuplicates().show()
//+------------+------------+----------+
//|           a|           b|       val|
//+------------+------------+----------+
//|202003101740|202003101700|1590554927|
//|202003101750|202003101700|1712384842|
//+------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Is dropDuplicates and distinct the same operation? @Shu

Comment: @coderWorld, One difference exists `distinct` will apply to the **whole dataframe** but `dropDuplicates` we can drop duplicates on `specific column` (or) on whole `dataframe` too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `dropDuplicates()`, that remove all duplicated rows:

```scala
uniqueDF = df.dropDuplicates()
```

Or your can specify the columns you wanna match:

```scala
uniqueDF = df.dropDuplicates("a","b")
```

Comment: use "left_semi" or left_anti --join method