# Pyspark : Subtract one dataframe from another based on one column value

Tags: pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes -
Dataframe A

```
+----+---+
|name| id|
+----+---+
|   a|  3|
|   b|  5|
|   c|  7|
+----+---+
```

Dataframe B

```
+----+---+
|name| id|
+----+---+
|   a|  3|
|   b| 10|
|   c| 13|
+----+---+
```

I want to subtract dataframe B from Dataframe A based on column id. So the result dataframe should be -

```
+----+---+
|name| id|
+----+---+
|   b|  5|
|   c|  7|
+----+---+
```

This is my code,

```
common = A.join(B, ['id'], 'leftsemi')
diff = A.subtract(common)
diff.show()
```

But it does not give expected result. Is there a simple way to achieve this which can subtract on dataframe from another based on one column value. Unable to find it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: subtract two DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537564/spark-subtract-two-dataframes)

Comment: But this is subtract based on all rows. I am looking it only based on one column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare the `id` column only, then use the `left_anti` join. This will give you the result that is in `df1` but not in `df2` by comparing the `id` column.

```
df1.join(df2, ['id'], 'left_anti').show(10, False)

+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|5  |b   |
|7  |c   |
+---+----+
```

---

`subtract` is all.

```
df1.subtract(df2).show(10, False)

+----+---+
|name|id |
+----+---+
|b   |5  |
|c   |7  |
+----+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

```
A.subtract(B).orderBy("id").show()

+----+---+
|name| id|
+----+---+
|   b|  5|
|   c|  7|
+----+---+
```